# Use method Region.setPath android

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I made a custom view in which I use `region.setPath(Rect, Path)` method. I also found that this method works if the hardware acceleration disabled. To do this, use the method `setLayerType (View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`.
As a result, the text is drawn on the canvas crooked, not filled and no clear path. Acceleration can not be enabled again. Who thread faced such problem?
[image: Sample problem]

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. Everything works fine, I am just set the parameters for the brush mPaintFont.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); and should mPaintFont.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);